# How to copy all the elements in an array list, then paste them to the array list? Example provided

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, arraylist

I want to copy all elements of ArrayList to the back of the ArrayList. For example, in my ArrayList, there are {1,2,3,4} and I want it to be like this --> {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4}.
How do I do it?

```
     for (int pos = 0; pos <  hand.size (); pos ++)
       {
           hand.add (hand.get(pos));
       }
```

This gives me an error saying out of memory...
Is there any way to make it work? 
Thank you

Comment: Add this to the loop `int endPos = hand.get(pos);` `hand.add(endPos);`Maybe also assign an int for the length. Not sure if it will work tho.

Comment: If you want to do it this way then calculate the size upfront and keep it in a variable.  Right now you've created an endless cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop looks roughly like:

```
is pos < hand.size()?
if so, add something to hand
pos++
```

which means that each time through the loop, pos increases, but hand.size() also increases, and so on. You get the out-of-memory error because the loop runs infinitely, and the list gets too big.

One way to do this:

```
int length = hand.size();
for (int pos = 0; pos < length; pos++) {
    hand.add(hand.get(pos));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
hand.addAll(new ArrayList<>(hand))
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you add an element, the size increases, so the loop never terminates. A simple fix is to save the size in a variable before the loop:

```
int size = hand.size()(
for (int pos = 0; pos <  size; pos ++)
{
    hand.add (hand.get(pos));
}
```

But the simplest way to do it is:

```
hand.addAll(hand); // Note: It is safe to call addAll() on itself
```